# Crystal Reports 2013 Generated SQL Syntax Error on Data Refresh(no quotes for column name with spaces)

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using SAP Crystal Reports 2013 (not the viewer), and working on a form with an ODBC (RDO) Data Source Connection, which was set up in the ODBC Data Source Administrator application using MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver.

The software incorrectly generates the SQL query that it uses to refresh/pull the data without quotes (All ODBC (RDO) connections are supposed to automatically generate this to prevent this exact type of issue).
This is an issue because the data source has column names that contain characters that require them to be surrounded in quotes.
This version and later of the Crystal Reports software will not allow you to directly edit the SQL query.

Updating the column names in the table I am pulling from is not an option, and I would rather not have to recreate the entire form using a query in the "add command" feature of the Database Expert.
Is there any fix?

Comment: Feel free to suggest clarifications instead of downvoting and moving on. This issue took forever to solve and I want anyone in this situation to be able to just look it up instead of waiting a few weeks for IT or stress out for a few hours like I did.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I've found is to download an earlier version of the MySQL ODBC driver (I specifically downloaded version 3.51) and to recreate the User Data Source in ODBC Data Source Administrator with that driver. All the information in the creation box should be exactly the same as the one you are currently connecting with. After that, you can go to Database->Set Data Source Location, then click on your data source on the top (make sure it is the line with the yellow cylinder), then go to the bottom section, create a connection using the user data source you just created in ODBC DSA, then select it and press update. No prompts will show up but you can test updating the connection and it should generate the SQL properly with quotes and remove the error.

Driver link:
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/3.51.html